# SQL database to track monthly bills (Beginner)

Tags: sql, express

I am interested in learning SQL. I span up a Server 2019 and installed SQL Express on it. I am currently going through a basic SQL course on Codecademy but figured it would be a lot better to practice with some hands on. I came up with an idea to create a database to track my monthly bills and finances. Once I have enough data then I can leverage some graphing tools to visually present the data.
Has anyone done something similar before? Any suggestions as how I should design the database/tables? Keep in mind that my SQL knowledge is still very limited.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and nobody can give a definitive answer.

I agree with your approach of trying it yourself in your own situation - that's a definite thumbs-up from me (indeed, when we get new employees, this is one of the best traits when reviewing them). So many times people learn so much by 'getting their hands dirty' so to speak (e.g., going on and trying it themselves).

However, I suggest starting with the examples they have to get the general concepts down - the usually choose at least decent examples.

Alternatively though, you could give it a shot. Just be prepared to be wrong and start again. But don't worry - in terms of value, having a shot and getting it wrong is worth *much* more than reading something and only half-understanding it.

If you are familiar with spreadsheets, I suggest

- Imagine how you would keep this on spreadsheets e.g., one sheet with bills that are due, and one sheet with your payments
- Each one of those sheets would represent a table in your database.

If you pay all your bills with one payment only (e.g., no installments), then it would be easier to do it with one spreadsheet (e.g., just listing all the bills on the left side, and their payment information on the right). In this case it may not be the best case for teaching yourself databases. On the other hand, if you do pay by installments, then this could be useful.

The big difference difference in approach, is that in databases, the rows are not inherently sorted. Instead, you typically give the rows an identifier (e.g., Bill_ID, or Payment_ID). And then the tables are linked e.g., for a given row in Payment table, you'd also include the Bill_ID to represent which bill the payment was for.

---

Update: More examples

To choose a relevant thing to try on databases, I suggest choosing things that are related to each other, but are separate from each other (e.g., not linked 1-to-1).

In the bills/payments above, if you paid each bill with one payment, they didn't need to be on separate tables. However, you could try other things e.g.,

- You live in a sharehouse where people pay for various things in a 'kitty' sysem (e.g., on each person's payday, they put in the amount they owe). In this case you may have a Bill table (which includes how it is split up, and when it was paid), and Person_Payments table which includes when people put money into the kitty
- You have a family with kids and chores. You have a Kids table (with their name, etc), a Chores table (listing chores and how much they are worth in pocket money) and then a Kids_Chores table listing the Kid_ID, Chore_ID and date. Whenever they do a chore it goes into Kids_Chores and that is used to determine their pocket money.
- You play various computer games and you want to track your win rate on them over time. You have one table for Game (with info about your user ID, etc), one for Game_Mode (which indicates, for a given game, what mode you were playing e.g., casual vs league, easy vs hard), then one for Game_Stats recording the date you played, the game and game_mode, and the number of games and number of wins.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. This gives me a starting point. I will try to make some progress now and ask more questions if I get stuck.